# conclude the local mass balance form from the global one

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I am engineer and not so deep in mathematics and i need your help please.

Let $\textbf{x}=[x,y,z]^T$ denotes a position vector of a point in a domain $\Omega_t$ say for example $\Omega_t = $ a$~$deforming sponge. Since the sponge is deforming, the domain shape will shange with time and will be a function of $\textbf{x}(t)$

Let $f = f(\textbf{x}, \ d\textbf{x}/dt, \ t)\in R$  be continuous function (which could be the mass or energy) defined over the domain $\Omega_t$ .

Engineers always say in their books that it is well known that if for arbitrary $\Omega_t$

$\int_{\Omega_t} f(\textbf{x}, \ d\textbf{x}/dt, \ t) \ d v= 0$

is true. then

$f(\textbf{x}, \ d\textbf{x}/dt, \ t) = 0$

how to prove this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Lets make life a little bit easier and suppress all the non-important arguments. Then, I think your question is:

Let $g : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, such that for all $U \subset \Omega$ we have $\int_U g(v) \, \mathrm{d} v = 0$. Then, $g(v) = 0$ for all $v \in \Omega$.

Let me sketch a proof for this statement (actually, I will supress some technicalities).

Assume, that $g(v) = 0$ for all $v \in \Omega$. Then, there must be a point $v$ with $g(v) > 0$ (in case $g(v) < 0$, you can argue similarly).

Since $g$ is continuous, there is a small ball $U$ around $v$, such that $g(u) > 0$ for all $u \in U$. But then, $\int_U g(u) \, \mathrm{d}u > 0$. This is a contradiction to your assumptions.

Comment: Thank you very much but I think we have $\int_U g(v, dv/dt) \, \mathrm{d} v = 0$. how will the proof go with this new argument $dv/dt$? It is really puzzling me as i am not mathematician

Comment: An argument $\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}t$ inside an integral $\int \ldots \mathrm{d}v$ does not make any sense...

Comment: Why? this can be found in poromechanics (mass  balance).                         the above problem can be reformulated into the following equation: $\int_{\Omega_0} df (\textbf{x}, t)/dt \,\, dV_0$ Where the domain is now a fixed domain (the domain at time t=0).

Comment: observe that $df/dt = \partial f /  \partial t + (\nabla f)  (dx/dt)$

Comment: or you may see the transport theorem in CFD. For example, page 8 in                                                                                                         http://www.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/num1/files/lectures/CFD.pdf

Comment: Yes, but if the differential of the integral is $dx$, only plain $x$ appear inside the integral.

Comment: And? Your integral is w.r.t. $dV_0$ and no $dV_0/dt$ appears inside...